# Performance comparison between the different use of IgniteCache.loadCache

Tags: ignite

I am using `IgniteCache.loadCache` to load data from Oracle into Ignite Cache with RDMS and Ignite Integration(https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/v1.7/docs/automatic-persistence)

My main class will start client mode Ignite and will write the data to the Ignite cluster of 3 nodes.

The following is the sql array that will query the same table with different condition

```
String[] sqlArray = new String[]{
 "select * from PERSON where id >=0 and id < 10000",
  "select * from PERSON where id >=10000 and id < 20000",
  ..
 "select * from PERSON where id >=10000000 and id < 10010000",

}
```

There are two options to run these sqls:

1. The first option is using the thread pool myself:

   `for (int i = 0; i< sqlArray.length; i++) {
         //submit the load through thread pool
         ThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
         cache.loadCache(null, Integer.class.getName(), sqlArray[i])
        }
   }`
2. The second option is:

   `cache.loadCache(null, sqlArray)`

I would ask from the performance's view, which one will be faster or they will not have significant difference in performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way looks right because the `loadCache` is used thread pool for launch `LoadCacheCustomQueryWorker` too and you save several ignite compute calls on each query.

**NB:** Please pay your attention to the arguments. The valid argument list in your case is:

```
Object[] args = new Object[] {
    Integer.class.getName(),
    "select * from PERSON where id >=0 and id < 10000",
    Integer.class.getName(),
    "select * from PERSON where id >=10000 and id < 20000",
    Integer.class.getName(),
    "select * from PERSON where id >=10000000 and id < 10010000"
}
```

So, the arguments count must be even. The first argument is **key type**, the second is **SQL query**.

Comment: Thanks @Taras. Thanks for the reminder for the API usage.From my observation, the option 2 is faster than option 1, I am just wondering why could this happen behind the scene.